# oracle INACTIVE session is blocking active session need a way to find sqlid which is blocking

Tags: java, oracle, session

I'm getting locks on oracle 11g database with information as follows

```
06112017:11:00:09    WELOPP@n1pv97/46581  (Session=('300,19867')Status=INACTIVE sqlid=>) blocking WELOPP@n1pv97/45876          (Session=('1803,10683')
                      Status=ACTIVE sqlid=fp5x2quh0zpqk) for the last 91850 seconds.

06112017:11:00:09    WELOPP@n1pv97/46581  (Session=('300,19867')Status=INACTIVE sqlid=>) blocking WELOPP@n1pv97/59864          (Session=('843,58185')
                       Status=ACTIVE sqlid=fp5x2quh0zpqk) for the last 5388 seconds.
```

How can an INACTIVE session can block an ACTIVE one?
How can I get more information on this INACTIVE session?

Answer (score 5):

It's quite simple for an `INACTIVE` session to block an `ACTIVE` one.  First, the difference between `ACTIVE` and `INACTIVE`.

An `ACTIVE` session is simply one that is currently in a database call.  An `INACTIVE` session is not.  A simple example would be, if you have a database connection via `SQL*Plus`, and it's sitting at the `SQL>` prompt, that's an `INACTIVE` session.  As soon as you execute a `SQL` or `PL/SQL` statement, the session will become `ACTIVE`.

Now, as to how an `INACTIVE` session can block an `ACTIVE` one, well, that's pretty straightforward.

Imagine two `SQL*Plus` sessions, both sitting idle at `SQL>` prompt.  Both are `INACTIVE`.  Now, session 1 executes:

```
update taba set col2='Hello world' where col1=1;
```

Session 1 will momentarily become `ACTIVE`, and take a lock on the row(s) it updated, and return to `INACTIVE` state.

Now, what happens when Session 2 executes the *same* SQL?

It will try to update the same row(s), but will be blocked by the `INACTIVE` Session 1, which has not committed, and therefore continues to hold a lock.  Session 2, meanwhile, is still `ACTIVE`, and will remain blocked and remain `ACTIVE` until session 1 either commits or rolls back.

Comment: Thanks Mark for the explanation. Any idea what can we do avoid such situation? Actually this is everyday's situation that INACTIVE session is blocking ACTIVE session. Is there any proactive way to avoid this? or less likely reactive way?

Comment: Really simple to understand explanations, Thanks.